# Windows System and DNS Client - constant querries for unknown local host

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, dns, forensics

I noticed today that there was significant traffic on all my connected network interfaces (loopback, 2 VMWare network adapters, ethernet and wifi).

[Wireshark home page showing traffic graphs. The traffic is very similar (if not the same) on all interfaces except WiFi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJSyJ.png)

This seemed weird since I was not using VMWare and didn't think I should have anything on loopback either. 
Digging into it, I saw that it was all MDNS, NBNS and LLMNR traffic originating from UDP ports 5353, 137 and variable, respectively, and all querying for `BRW30F7727FAC8E` - a host unknown to me.

[MDNS, NBNS and LLMR traffic - ignore the errors due to IP checksum offloading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HXer.png)

Using netstat, I was able to see that I've got PIDs 2424 (DNS Client) and 4 (System) bound to all interfaces on UDP 5353 and 137.

```
C:\>netstat -abno | grep 5353
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*                                    2424
  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*                                    2424

C:\>netstat -abno | grep 137
  UDP    169.254.103.175:137    *:*                                    4
  UDP    169.254.178.212:137    *:*                                    4
  UDP    192.168.2.14:137       *:*                                    4
  UDP    192.168.47.1:137       *:*                                    4
  UDP    192.168.159.1:137      *:*                                    4
```

So now I'm wondering why I have the system itself querying continuously for this unknown host and if the DNS Client is making these requests by itself or on behalf of another process (perhaps System?).

I was able to make it disappear by black-holing `BRW30F7727FAC8E` in my hosts file which now gives me some interesting traffic where I'm seeing an incrementing range of ports on my machine trying to connect to `BRW30F7727FAC8E` on tcp 515 and 80. According to online resources, tcp port 515 has been associated with malware and printer spoolers.

[Traffic following hosts file black-holing. I assigned the unknwown host to 127.0.0.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMXn3.png)

So my question is, does anyone know how I could keep tracking down the root cause of this traffic and attempt to stop it at the source?

Thank you.

note: I checked my DNS cache and found nothing.

Comment: Do you have a Brother printer installed? (`control.exe printers` → Print Server Settings → Ports)

Comment: @grawity Ahh! Guilty as charged. BRW30F7727FAC8E is defined as a TCP/IP port for a Brother printer. The printer is not on the network anymore, probably the reason for the constant querrying (never give up I guess). I switched the printer to use another port however, this has not stopped the queries!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hostname matches the pattern `BRW<macaddress>` which is the default hostname used by Brother printers, and all traffic shown in your logs (SNMP queries, attempts to connect to the LPR port) is typical for Windows' print spooler trying to contact a TCP-based network printer using the traditional [lpr protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_Printer_Daemon_protocol).

(lpr is a very minimal protocol and does not have in-band feedback, instead the client is expected to query printer status using SNMP. If you expand the query, you'll see that many of the OIDs are printing-related.)

Open `control.exe printers` → "Print Server Properties" → "Ports" and you'll find a 'port' definition for this hostname. (Ports can exist without a corresponding printer, but since Windows keeps contacting it, most likely there *is* a printer installed as well, and probably even has some jobs queued.)